# Можно ли создать установщик для python программы?

Tags: python

Можно ли сделать готовую программу с установщиком и если можно какие есть инструменты для создания установщика?

Comment: Компиляция не имеет никакого отношения к запуску без установки python. Даже скомпилированные на C++ программы требуют устанавливать стандартную библиотеку и какой-нибудь vcredist правильной версии.

Comment: Для сброки установщика со встроенным питоном можно использовать какой-нибудь pyinstaller, но он тоже не имеет к компиляции никакого отношения.

Comment: nuitka, pyinstaller, py2exe

Comment: cx_freeze ещё есть

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если нужен именно установщик под Windows аля `setup.exe` то сначала `pyinstaller` для генерации всех нативных `dll` и `exe`, а затем `nsis` для создания установщика. В результате получится `setup.exe` с вашей программой, который при нужных настройках  установит программу в нужный каталог, создаст ключи в реестре, сделает ярлыки, создаст `uninstall.exe` и много чего еще.